# jQuery Validation plugin errorPlacement with wildcard selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, wildcard, errorplacement

I am using the jQuery Validation plugin and trying to use the `errorPlacement` callback function with a wildcard selector. I have tried countless permutations of the wildcard syntax with and without the `.attr` method (and have tried several other methods) and and can't get it to work right.

I have read several dozen threads about wildcards, as well as api documentation but none address their use in a function like this where the use of 'element' is required. can't seem to get my head around it...

```
/*** This will work but only for the specified string ****/
if  (element.attr("name") == "cdlradio1" )
```

I want to select all input elements beginning with 'cdlradio'

```
var $validator = $("#myform").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
if (element.attr("[name^='cdlradio']"))
    error.insertAfter(element.closest(".bootradlab"));
else
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not in the proper format...

```
if (element.attr("[name^='cdlradio']")) ...
```

Because, [the `.attr()` method is looking for **an attribute** as its only argument](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).  Clearly, `[name^='cdlradio']` is a *selector*, **not** an attribute.  You don't need a *selector* since your target element is *already* selected by the `element` argument.

You have to get the field `name` and check to see if it contains your string...

```
if (element.attr('name').indexOf('cdlradio') >= 0) ...
```

**"Wildcard" DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/aBrL2/2/**

**BTW** - [`^=` is the "starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), **not** a wild-card.  However, my solution above is a true wild-card as it doesn't care about position as long as the string occurs someplace.  My answer can easily be converted to a "starts with" by changing the `>=` operator into a `==` operator.

**"Starts With" DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/aBrL2/3/**

Comment: I knew there was something wrong with using the .attr() method since i was already referencing the element name in what i thought was a wildcard statement. Using indexOf is definitely the better way to go. Thanks for the clarification and for the fix. Works perfectly!